# What is the canonical way to do a one-to-many outer join with NULLs and case classes?

Tags: scala, anorm

This is a very common use-case - a simple 1:N join across two tables.

Tables:

```
USER
user_id email
1       a@a.com
2       b@b.com
3       c@c.com

USER_ROLE
user_id role
1       user
1       admin
2       user
```

In this case it needs to be an outer join since a user may not have any roles.

The outer join returns a result set like this:

```
user_id email     role
1       a@a.com   user
1       a@a.com   admin
2       b@b.com   user
3       c@c.com   NULL
```

Here you can see user_id 3 has no roles.

Model:

```scala
case class User(userId: Long, email: String, roles: List[Role])

sealed trait Role
case object UserRole extends Role
case object AdminRole extends Role
```

There is a mapping required from the role name string in the database to the corresponding case class object:

```scala
object Role {
   def apply(name: String): Role = name match {
       case "user" => UserRole
       case "admin" => AdminRole
   }
}
```

Data access:

```scala
object Users {

    def mapper = {
        get[Long]   ("user_id"  ) ~
        get[String] ("email"    ) ~
        (get[String]("role_name")?) map {
            case userId~email~role =>
                ((userId, email), role)
        }
    }

    def findById(userId: Long) : Option[User] = {
        DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
            SQL("""
                SELECT
                    u.user_id,
                    u.email,
                    r.role
                FROM
                    user u
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    user_role r
                ON
                    u.user_id = r.user_id
            """)
            .on('user_id -> userId)
            .as(Users.mapper.*)
            .groupBy(_._1)
            .map {
                case ((userId, email), rest)
                    => User(userId, email, rest.unzip._2.map(role => Role(role.orNull)))
            }.headOption
        }
    }
}
```

The mapper returns a tuple where each instance contains the duplicated user data and a role.

This works for everything except the case where there are no roles, the map function ultimately tries to execute Role(null) and fails.

So in this case where the role is NULL the user instance should end up with an empty List() rather than a list of roles. Essentially, I do not want to execute the innermost map function.

So, I changed that map clause to this:

```scala
.map {
    case ((userId, email), rest)
        => User(userId, email, {
            val roles = rest.unzip._2
            roles.head match {
                case Some(role) => roles.map(role => Role(role.orNull))
                case None => List()
            }
        })
}.headOption
```

This all does actually work, but is it the canonical idiomatic way?

Comment: I think you should you Anorm streaming support to live combine such data, but it should be clearer with by adding to the question an example of raw rows you may get along with Scala instances that you want to be parsed from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to Anorm 2.3, you could use streaming as following to parse hierarchical/to be customly aggregated rows.

```scala
import anorm.{ Row, SQL }

@annotation.tailrec
def parse(res: Stream[Row], map: Map[Int, User]): Iterable[User] = res.headOption match {
  case Some(row) => {
    val id = row[Int]("user_id")
    val user = map.lift(id).getOrElse(User(id, row[String]("email"), Nil))
    val role = row[Option[String]]("role") flatMap {
      case "user" => Some(UserRole)
      case "admin" => Some(AdminRole)
      case _ => None // Unsupported - Error handling
    }

    parse(res.tail, map + (
      id -> role.fold(user)(r => user.copy(roles = roles :+ r))))
  }
  case _ => map.values
}

val res: Stream[Row] = SQL("SELECT ...").apply()
val users = parse(res, Map.empty[Int, User])
```

Using current Anorm master (next streaming support), you can use `withResult`.

```scala
import anorm.{ Cursor, SQL }

@annotation.tailrec
def parse(cur: Option[Cursor], map: Map[Int, User]): Iterable[User] = cur match {
  case Some(cursor) => {
    val row = cursor.row
    val id = row[Int]("user_id")
    val user = map.lift(id).getOrElse(User(id, row[String]("email"), Nil))
    val role = row[Option[String]]("role") flatMap {
      case "user" => Some(UserRole)
      case "admin" => Some(AdminRole)
      case _ => None // Unsupported - Error handling
    }

    parse(cursor.next, map + (
      id -> role.fold(user)(r => user.copy(roles = roles :+ r))))
  } 
  case _ => map.value
}

val users = SQL("SELECT ...").withResult(parse(_, Map.empty[Int, User]))
```

With Anorm master, you can also do it with `.fold`.

```scala
import anorm.SQL

val map: Map[Int, User] = SQL("SELECT ...").fold(Map.empty[Int, User]) { (map, row) =>
  val id = row[Int]("user_id")
  val user = map.lift(id).getOrElse(User(id, row[String]("email"), Nil))
  val role = row[Option[String]]("role") flatMap {
    case "user" => Some(UserRole)
    case "admin" => Some(AdminRole)
    case _ => None // Unsupported - Error handling
  }

  map + (id -> role.fold(user)(r => user.copy(roles = roles :+ r)))
}
val users = map.values
```

This streaming approach can also be combined with `SqlParser` usage. Instead of using `row[T]("label")` to extract each value on current row, parse like `SqlParser.int("user_id") ~ SqlParser.str("email") map { ... }` could be apply on the row (not sure it will be better in this case).

> Not only syntax has been updated for streaming support on latest version, but also performance (memory usage).

Comment: I am new to this, but does the tail recursion approach make a recursive call for each row? So if I have 10k users each with 10 roles I get 100k rows and 100k-1 nested recursive calls to parse()? Or does the recursion unwind with each new user id?

Comment: The tailrec is optimised. You can add `println` to see how it proccesses rows.

Comment: OK, let me try this and get it working before accepting your answer. I have to say as a newcomer, even though I really like Anorm and much prefer it to something like Slick, in this case the solution seems somewhat more complicated than the problem.

Comment: Anorm is not ORM, that is to say not simple case have to be handle in custom way. Advantage is that there is a full control of the parsing and memory usuage (only keep what you're interested in). It make sense for me in such case.

Comment: You say Anorm "master" for the new streaming features, does this mean waiting for Play 2.4?

Comment: Either waiting for 2.3.5 or build it from sources.